# Imprimir um numero gradual de caracteres

Tags: php

Utilizando uma estrutura de repetição, imprima na tela o seguinte:

*

**

***

****

*****

******

*******

Comment: Pode começar editando com um título mais objetivo e curto. Adicionando sua tentativa de resolver o problema também.

Comment: Oi Diego eu melhorei o post!

Comment: Pode melhorar bem mais... Não use o titulo como descrição. E o que voce tentou? Adicione seu código tambem.

Comment: Informe quais foram suas tentativas. O intuito é ajuda-lo, não fazer pra você

Answer (score 3):

Entendo que como se trata de um exercício, a resposta do @DiegoF é a mais correta para a pergunta.

Apenas como referência, fica uma versão usando `str_repeat`, mais adequada se for para uma aplicação real:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < 7; ++$i ) echo str_repeat( '*', $i ) . "\n";
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/7l7Mrs)**.

Se for usar em HTML, troque o `"\n"` por `'<br>'`, ou mesmo por `"<br>\n"` (e duplique caso queira as linhas em branco).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar 2 laços, o mais externo controla a mudança de linha e outro imprime a quantidade respectiva de `*` daquela linha.

Veja:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++){
        echo "*";
    }
    echo "\n\n";
}
```

Veja funcionando no [**IDEONE**](http://ideone.com/wpcg7a). Como você não deixou claro se esse espaçamento entre linhas fazia parte, adicionei uma quebra a mais, assim a saida fica:

```
*

**

***

****

*****

******

*******
```

Comment: Seria interessante quem deu o downvote me mostrar onde está o problema na resposta. Ela atende ao solicitado.

Comment: Talvez a pessoa nao tenha gostado de vc entregar o exercicio pronto, mas acho que não é motivo pra -1. De qq forma, eu upei.

Comment: @Bacco então é só implicância mesmo, porque o usuário não entende como funciona laços, naes edições ele citou que não entende "ciclos. Mas  por outro lado, pequei em não explicar o que está acontecendo, vou complementar.

Comment: mesmo assim acho sacanagem o -1, entendo que a minha é só um complemento, pra exercício a sua cumpre melhor a finalidade.